# wp8.1 webview and sending javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, windows-phone

I have a method in objective-c that sends some javascript auth to a web server, it works fine. But now I'm developing the same app for windows phone 8.1 and 10 and can't work out the correct method or format. The iOS function is, it sends a token and device os i have tried `invokescriptasync("eval", new[] { sessionTokenJS });` in `DOMContentLoaded` but it just crashes.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    // JWT token - required for authentication
    NSString *sessionToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", [[ConnectionManager sharedManager] getAuthToken]];
    NSString *setSessionTokenJavaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"javascript:localStorage.setItem('jwt-token', '%@')", sessionToken];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setSessionTokenJavaScript];

    // Required to identify the mobile device loading the web view
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"javascript:localStorage.setItem('mobile_device_os', 'iOS')"];

    [webView stopLoading];
    self.webView = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's ok, i worked it out, inline js parenthesis were wrong for the parameters